# Memory leak when using custom text in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm working on my React Native project and I'm getting the famous "`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`" sometimes when I'm using my custom text component. This is quite weird, because I'm following the same steps as the docs. Here's the component:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { Text, TextStyle } from "react-native";

import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import {
  useFonts,
  Montserrat_500Medium,
  Montserrat_800ExtraBold,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat";

import { colors } from "./ConstantStyles";

type CustomTextProps = {
  style?: TextStyle | TextStyle[];
  variant?: string;
};

const PrimaryText: FunctionComponent<CustomTextProps> = ({
  children,
  style,
  variant,
}) => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat_500Medium,
    Montserrat_800ExtraBold,
  });

  const passedStyles = Array.isArray(style)
    ? Object.assign({}, ...style)
    : style;

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <Text
        style={[
          {
            fontFamily:
              variant === "bold"
                ? "Montserrat_800ExtraBold"
                : "Montserrat_500Medium",
          },
          { ...passedStyles },
        ]}
      >
        {children}
      </Text>
    );
  }
};

export default PrimaryText;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure, this is the component giving warning. If so, it might be because of fonts taking time to load and before its even loaded, component was removed/unmounted, to avoid this try loading it once only at app start and use its reference everywhere, probably using redux-store or context

Comment: That's probably it, but it seems very inconvenient to have to use context for all of this. It should just have something like the UseEffect cleanup function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try loading the fonts in async manner and keep a check in your `useEffect` to setState only if its not unmounted, like given in this [expo documentation using-fontloadasync-instead-of-the-usefonts-hook](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/#using-fontloadasync-instead-of-the-usefonts-hook)

Here is the [expo snack example](https://snack.expo.io/!fuzskAJI)

Also, I would suggest to load fonts from local cache instead from direct web, which will increase the app size a little bit, but fonts will load much faster, just like given in the above example.